# Adding ES5 functions to vuejs app compiled with babel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

### Question

How do I add my variables to [My VueJS app](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/wXbVLB) that uses babel?

### Background

I have an app that is using Vue and Axios. It works fine but I added functionality to dynamically reformat a string, The Code that reformats a string works in [my pen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/Vdowew) works fine.

```
var brewer = document.getElementsByClassName('author-raw');
for (var contrib = 0; contrib < brewer.length; contrib++) {
  var matches = brewer[contrib].innerHTML.match(/(.*)\s\<([a-z]*)\>/);
  var output = `${matches[1]} <a href="https://www.twitter.com/${matches[2]}" target="_blank">@${matches[2]}</a>`;
  brewer[contrib].closest('div').querySelector('cite').innerHTML = output;
}
```

I just now need to add it to [my beer education app](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/wXbVLB?editors)

I looked at the [documentation for vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) and I would guess that I need to add it inside the created block? It did not work in there.

```
created() {
  //code goes here?
}
```

In react I could but this almost anywhere.

---

### Edit 1

I forgot that I should have converted over to ES6, so updated JS is

```
const brewer = document.getElementsByClassName('author-raw');
for (let contrib = 0; contrib < brewer.length; contrib++) {
  const matches = brewer[contrib].innerHTML.match(/(.*)\s\<([a-z]*)\>/);
  const output = `${matches[1]} <a href="https://www.twitter.com/${matches[2]}" target="_blank">@${matches[2]}</a>`;
  brewer[contrib].closest('div').querySelector('cite').innerHTML = output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't try to manipulate the DOM that way, instead, manipulate the data.

Change your `addBeer` method to:

```
addBeer() {
  axios.get('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/random')
    .then(response => {
      let api = response.data[0];

      // parse contributor here
      let contributor = api.contributed_by
      let matches = contributor.match(/(.*)\s\<([a-z]*)\>/)

      let apiInfo = {
        name: api.name,
        desc: api.description,
        img: api.image_url,
        tips: api.brewers_tips,

        // and add both parts to your data
        contributor: matches[1],
        twitter: `@${matches[2]}`,

        tagline: api.tagline,
        abv: api.abv,
        food: api.food_pairing
      };
      this.beers.push(apiInfo)
      if (this.bottomVisible()) {
        this.addBeer()
      }
  })
}
```

And change the template to use the parsed data:

```
<span class="author-raw" aria-hidden="true">
  {{ beer.contributor }} 
  <a style="color: white" :href="`https://www.twitter.com/${beer.twitter}`">{{beer.twitter}}</a>
</span>
```

Here is your [codepen updated](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/gKVbgz?editors=1010).

With Vue, if you start manipulating the DOM, you are almost invariably doing it wrong unless you are trying to integrate with an external library.

An alternative approach would be to write a small functional component.

```
const Contributor = {
  functional: true,
  render(h, context){
    const {contributor} = context.props
    // leave if there is no contributor
    if (!contributor) return null

    const parsed = contributor.match(/(.*)\s\<([A-Za-z]*)\>/)
    // leave if we couldn't parse the contributor
    if (!parsed || parsed.length < 2) return null

    const [original, name, handle] = parsed
    const twitter = `@${handle}`
    const href = `https://www.twitter.com/${twitter}`
    const props = {attrs: {href}, style:{color: "white", marginLeft: ".5em"}}
    return h("span", {attrs:{"aria-hidden": true}}, [name, h("a", props, [twitter])])
  }
}
```

And change your template to:

```
<div class="author">
  <contributor :contributor="beer.contributor"></contributor>
   <cite></cite>
</div>
```

Here is your [codepen updated](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MXNYXw?editors=1010) to show that.

Comment: I have a followup question regarding Vue, when you did this `:contributor="beer.contributor"` what is that called so i can look that up, I use React mostly so trying to understand how Vue works differently.

Comment: @JGallardo That syntax represents passing a property to the component. `contributor` is defined as a property, and `beer.contributor` is the value passed. Sometimes you will see it written in the long form, `v-bind:contributor="beer.contributor"`. The `:` is a short hand for `v-bind`. Here is [the basic documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props). The last pen I linked in the answer includes a simpler `NonFunctionalContributor` component that doesn't use a render function that might be easier for a person new to Vue to understand.

Comment: Also, since this approach does not manipulate the DOM like my original approach, would i be safe to remove the `cite` ? or perhaps i can even nest the `<contributor>` component inside of it? before I was populating innerHTML to the cite.

Comment: @JGallardo Absolutely. Or you can remove the empty cite and make the span a cite. I updated the pen to that effect. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MXNYXw?editors=1010